# Determining $\lim_{h\to 0} \inf|f(x+h)|dx$ when $f$ is integrable

Tags: real-analysis

I am trying to show
 $f$ is (Lebesgue) integrable $\Rightarrow$ $\\lim_{h\to 0}\int|f(x+h)+f(x)|dx$ exists.

$\\lim_{h\to 0}\int|f(x+h)+f(x)|dx\le\ \lim_{h\to 0}\int|f(x+h)|dx+\int|f(x)|dx.$
If the limit can pass through then $\int\lim_{h\to0}|f(x+h)|$ exists since it goes to $\int|f(x)|$, but am I allowed to pass the limit through the integral? I am not aware of any theorems of this sort.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We have $$\left|\int_A  (|f(x+h)|+|f(x)| )d\ell -\int_A 2|f(x)|d\ell \right| \leq \int_A ||f(x+h)|+|f(x)| -2|f(x)||d\ell \leq\int_A |f(x+h) -f(x)|d\ell =||f_h -f||_{L_1} \to 0 \mbox{ if } h\to 0.$$
Hence $$\lim_{h\to 0} \int_A (|f(x+h)| +|f(x)| )d\ell =2\int_A |f(x)| d\ell.$$

Comment: How  do you know you can pass the limit through the integral?